# I want to display a list in an listbox

Tags: c#

I am having trouble sending a `List<>` to a textbox and i am not sure what the trouble is. I have checked so the List actually has values in it and that it gets properly transfered from the class into this block.

The code:

```
  public void Listtest(List<string> m_customers)
    {
        lstRegistry.Items.Clear();


        for (int index = 0; index == m_customers.Count; index++)
        {
            lstRegistry.Items.Add(m_customers[index]);
        }
    }
```

The other class that is sending the `List<>`

```
     class CustomManager
{
    //private List<Customer> m_customers;
    List<string> m_customers = new List<string>();        

    public void CreateNewString(string adresslist, string emaillist, string phonelist, string namelist)
    {
        MainForm strIn = new MainForm();
        string newlist = string.Format("{0,-3} {1, -10} {2, -20} {3, -30}", namelist, phonelist, emaillist, adresslist);           
        m_customers.Add(newlist);  //líst is created.
        strIn.Listtest(m_customers);           
    }
}
```

I just cant get it to work and I am really stuck. :/

Thanks for any and all help and ideas!!!

//Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the loop condition to: `index < m_customers.Count`

**Edit**
Also you might want to create a class for this data:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
}
```

So you can make a list of Persons: `List<Person>`

Answer (score 2):

Erno's answer should take care of your issue, but I would also recommend that you read up on [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  Using this would change your code from:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < m_customers.Count; index++)
    {
        lstRegistry.Items.Add(m_customers[index]);
    }
```

to

```
    foreach (string cust in m_customers)
    {
        lstRegistry.Items.Add(cust );
    }
```

Which I would argue is easier to read.